# can not set fix width with div tag

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make an image slider with 60% width of the body,the html code as following:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;
}

.slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide1 {
  background-image: url('assets/img/slide1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <span>slider1</span>
      </div>

      <div class="slide slide2">
        <span>slider1</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

but the background image i have set is expanded full width of its container, not as 60%. i am wondering what i am doing wrong here? should i set the slide class as `display:inline`property here?

Comment: I hope I've understood what you are asking - Try adding `position: relative;` to the `.wrapper` div

Comment: Hey laura, thanks for your reply, i was intend to set each slide class with 60% width and add a background image on each of them. but my code was not working

Comment: Code is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/wjxcqf9z/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 60%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
}
.slider-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.slide{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.slide1{
    background-image: url('assets/img/slide1.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you should define height for .slider-wrapper then in .slide add width:100% and height: 100%

I think this may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems alright to me, each slide is displaying 60% out of 80% wrapper.

If you refer to snippet below, the grey is `.wrapper` displaying 80% out 100% and pink image is the `.slide` displaying 60% out of 80% wrapper.

**Example:**

```css
.wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background: grey;
}
     .slider-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height:100%;
    }

    .slide{
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100%;
}
.slide1{
background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/a32da3/fff');
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="slide slide1">
            <span>slider1</span>
        </div>

        <div class="slide slide2">
            <span>slider2</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working absolutely fine. Here issue is about you don't have content to expand your `.slider-wrapper`. And moreover you are using image as background not in `<img>` tag so it doesn't have enough space to show your background-image. So you are must set `height` to your `.slider-wrapper` or update with some content as like below snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60%;  
}

.slide {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slide1 {
  background-image: url('https://ak.picdn.net/assets/cms/97e1dd3f8a3ecb81356fe754a1a113f31b6dbfd4-stock-photo-photo-of-a-common-kingfisher-alcedo-atthis-adult-male-perched-on-a-lichen-covered-branch-107647640.jpg');/*dummy image*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider-wrapper">
      <div class="slide slide1">
        <span>slider1</span>
        <p>some content</p>
        <p>some content</p>
        <p>some content</p>
        <p>some content</p>
        <p>some content</p>
        <p>some content</p>
        <p>some content</p>
        <p>some content</p>
      </div>

      <div class="slide slide2">
        <span>slider2</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```